# How to import MobaXterm sessions from inf file?

Tags: import, inf, mobaxterm

I have got "inf" file but not able to find option to import it ! So please let me know How to import MobaXterm sessions from inf file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution !

Copy "inf" file to & start the MobaXterm it will import your sessions !

```
C:\Users\xxx\Documents\MobaXterm\home
```